# test batch statements directly in powershell without wrapping the call in a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am writing a batch file to automate a task using vscode where I get a powershell as my default shell.

The line `if not exist build (md build)` produces errors in powershell.

When I pack the same line into a batch file called `test.bat` I can call `./test.bat` and get the expected behaviour.

Is there a way to test my batch statements directly in the powershell?

Comment: Change your default shell, The Command Palette should offer you the Terminal > Select Default Shell command, where you can change the default to `cmd.exe` if that's what you prefer. You can always use View > Toggle Integrated Terminal in normal use to pop back into `powershell.exe`.

Comment: @Compo thanks - that is an option for me. Would you know of a way I could pass a line to powershell and have it interpreted as a cmd line?

Comment: What about something like `cmd /k "if not exist \`"build\\`" md \`"build\`""`? or probably simpler to use, as it requires less modification, `cmd /k 'if not exist "build\" md "build"'`. This will run your command in `cmd.exe` in your powershell shell, and will continue to use `cmd.exe` in that session, until you tell it not to. But as these two shells have differences, you're going to have to be careful whichever you use in the initial command, because of their differences in quote, and escape characters. _(Use `Exit` to return to the powershell prompt when you've finished in the cmd prompt)_

Comment: Of course, you do not have to begin with an initial command, so could just type `cmd` at the PowerShell prompt, and this will also run the `cmd.exe` process within that shell. Use it as necessary for testing your commands, then type `exit`, and press `[ENTER]`,  to return to the PS prompt again.

Comment: @Compo jup - totally blanked on using cmd. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell use `Test-Path`:

```
If(!(Test-Path ".\build")){md ".\build"}
```

Or another way..

```
Cmd /c "your statement"
```

Get error code in $LastExitCode

Comment: thanks for the snippet. I am looking for a way to test my batch line in powershell, If I copy your line into the batch file I am working on it will fail on the system I deploy it to.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, **passing statements to `cmd.exe` via `/c` is *not* the same as executing them *in a batch file***.

While in many cases it won't make a difference, there are - sadly - differences in how statements are processed *interactively* (which is what `cmd /c ...` amounts to):

- only in batch files can you escape `%` characters as `%%`
- only in batch files do `for` loop variables use `%%` rather than `%` (e.g., `%%i`, not `%i`)

For instance, the statement `for %%i in (1,2,3) do echo [%%i]` - which is perfectly valid in a batch file - does *not* work via `cmd /c`:

```
PS> cmd /c 'for %%i in (1,2,3) do echo [%%i]'
%%i was unexpected at this time.
```

---

**Solution**:

Save the statement(s) of interest to a *temporary batch file*, invoke it, then remove it.

This is cumbersome, but the [`Native`](https://github.com/mklement0/Native) module (authored by me) with its `ins` (`Invoke-NativeShell`) command can do the heavy lifting for you:

```
# Install the Native module for the current user.
PS> Install-Module Native -Scope CurrentUser

# Both command strings below would *not* work when passed to `cmd /c`

PS> ins 'for %%i in (1,2,3) do echo [%%i]'
[1]
[2]
[3]

PS> ins 'echo %%SystemDrive%% is %SystemDrive%'
%SystemDrive% is C:
```