# I am trying to run several PowerShell commands from a batch script, however the "%" symbol does not get transferred

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to run several PowerShell commands from a batch script, however the "%" symbol does not get transferred to PowerShell.

For example, writing the following in a command prompt window:

```
powershell -Command "& {echo 'per%entage'}"
```

Will print:

```
per%entage
```

which is what I want, however if I save the same command into a .bat or .cmd file, it instead prints:

```
perentage
```

Why is it ignoring the "%" symbol? Is there a way to make it transfer properly? I'm especially confused that it works in a command prompt window, but not in a batch script. You'd think both would either work or not work.

Comment: had you performed even a basic search before asking this question, you would have learnt the % character needs to be escaped with itself in batch files; so: `%%` instead of `%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very unfortunately, `cmd.exe`'s behavior differs with respect to command invocations from an *interactive prompt* vs. *from a batch file* with respect to how `%` characters are interpreted.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64217193/45375) for background information.

Therefore, when calling *from a batch file*, a `%` char. that is to interpreted *verbatim*, must be escaped as `%%`:

```
:: From a *batch file*.
powershell -Command "'per%%entage'"
```

Note:

- `echo` is a built-in alias for the [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlet, whose explicit use is rarely needed - see [this answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for more information.
- Invocation of commands (symbolized as `...` here) in the form  `& { ... }` is virtually never needed  when using the [PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) - just use `...` as-is.
- Generally, for predictable invocation, it's worth using the `-NoProfile` switch as well - *before* the `-Command` parameter - so as to bypass loading of PowerShell's profile files, which are primarily meant for *interactive* sessions.